# TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'a' has DataType not in list of allowed values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
_X = np.arange(1, 7).reshape((2, 3))
_Y = np.arange(1, 7).reshape((3, 2))

X = tf.convert_to_tensor(_X)
Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(_Y)

# Matrix multiplication
out1 = tf.matmul(X, Y)
```

For it, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'a' has DataType int64 not in list of allowed values: float16, float32, float64, int32, complex64, complex128
```

I am using the latest version of Tensorflow. What could be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't do matrix multiplication with tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414905/cant-do-matrix-multiplication-with-tensorflow)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inputs to tf.matmul accepts only these dtypes :

```
a: Tensor of type float16, float32, float64, int32, complex64, complex128 and rank > 1.
```

Changing dtype of X and Y to above dtypes works.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
_X = np.arange(1, 7).reshape((2, 3))
_Y = np.arange(1, 7).reshape((3, 2))

X = tf.convert_to_tensor(_X,dtype=tf.int32)
Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(_Y,dtype=tf.int32)

# Matrix multiplication
out1 = tf.matmul(X, Y)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(out1))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way:

```
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
   y_true = tensorflow.cast(y_true, tensorflow.float32)
   y_pred = tensorflow.cast(y_pred, tensorflow.float32)
   ...
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but this one did.